# Allow "drupal-N" tags to be migrated from other sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

When a question is migrated from other sites, any tag that matches `^drupal-?\d+.*$` is removed. The problem is that *Stack Overflow* uses [drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6), and [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7); as users on *Stack Overflow* are used to have those tags, they don't write in the question for which Drupal version they are interested in. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000925/link-a-content-types-field-to-the-user-profile as example.) As consequence, when one of those questions is migrated to *Drupal Answers*, that information is lost.

Rather than having those tags blocked, it would be better to allow tags like drupal-6, which are then made synonym of the actual tags being used on *Drupal Answers* (e.g. [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6)). If the version tag is not really necessary, because the question applies to any Drupal version, we will edit the question accordingly.
It is rather better to allow those tags than keeping to ask to the OP "For which Drupal version are you asking the question?" when the OP did originally shown for which Drupal version s/he was interested.

The black-list entry should be changed from `^drupal-?\d+.*$` to `^drupal-?\d+.+$.` In this way, tags like drupal-7 would be allowed, and set as synonym of the correct tag. Other tags, like drupal-7beta would not be allowed. As the latter is not used on *Stack Overflow* (the site from where most of the questions are migrated), it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[A spot-check](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated) indicates that the volume of inbound migrations is not terribly high, with the volume of inbound migrations having valid version-tags on the source question being even lower and those referencing versions other than 7 quite rare indeed.

Given that [these versioned tags were originally removed for the benefit of the folks asking questions *here*](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok), and those users are producing a much larger volume of questions, I don't think adding these tags back purely to benefit migrations is a good idea.

Comment: What would be the damage of having [tag:drupal-7] as synonym of [tag:7], as long as [tag:7] is seen in questions? The damage is that a question tagged only with drupal-7 would not have any useful tag, when migrated.

Comment: If you create the tag - even as a synonym - as soon as someone types "drupal" in the tag field it'll pop up. Since that's the most obvious tag, that's the one they'll pick. You occasionally see this prompting misuse even with *blatantly* inappropriate tags like drupal-commerce - when the tag actually *might* apply (and the rules for when it should / shouldn't are hazy), this gets even worse. And as I noted, there's next-to-no benefit, since questions on older versions of Drupal are almost never migrated here.

Comment: I have never had to edit away [tag:drupal-commerce] or any other tag starting with drupal from any questions. As a matter of fact, [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74164/how-to-search-in-2-views-or-blocks-through-one-filter) created by a new user doesn't even use any tag starting with drupal. The only problem for users coming from Drupal forums is using a version tag, since they are used to always say for which version their question is; as soon as they understand the right tag is [tag:7], they would start abusing that, but that didn't happen, so far.

Comment: Something appears wrong to me in the argumentation used in this answer. "I" just followed the [spot-check](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated) link (I was curios), and got an error that I'm not authorised yet, it includes something about "... earned at least 10000 reputation ..." (OK, that I understand, makes sense). But Shog9 only has a reputation of 101 right now. **So how can Shog9 use as an argumentation whatever is visible there** (for authorized users like kiamlaluno with +52k ...)? Must be something I don't understand.

Comment: Shog9 is staff - Community Coordinator for Stack Exchange - https://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/users/885/shog9. His access to site data is not tied to the reputation system.