# Tag synonym: [drupal-7] → [7]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Could someone add [drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7) as synonym of [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7)?

Answer (score 3):

That tag is explicitly blacklisted - there's no need to have `drupal` as part of the tag name, as this is an exclusively Drupal-oriented site.

For reference these are the regular expressions used to prevent those tags from being created:

- `^drupal$`
- `^drupal-?\d+.*$`

We couldn't create that tag if we wanted to :)

You can find this discussed in detail here: [Numeric version tags considered ... OK](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using [drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7) as synonym of [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) would be useful for those questions that are migrated from Stack Overflow, where drupal-7 is one of the available tags. Without [drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7) as synonym, drupal-7 is going to be removed from those questions, and important information is removed from the question.

In order for this to be possible, a Community Coordinator should answer to [Allow "drupal-N" tags to be migrated from other sites](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/allow-drupal-n-tags-to-be-migrated-from-other-sites), which is what doesn't allow us to set [drupal-n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-n) as synonym of [n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n). Moderators cannot change the entries for blacklisted user input; that is why we depend from somebody else to fix this.

Anyway, when a question is migrated, there is always a link to the original question. This means that the tags used when asking the question are always visible. If a tag is missing, everybody can look at the tags used from the OP, and add the equivalent one, if needed.

Apart preserving the tags used when migrating a question, there isn't much use of that synonym tag.
Synonym tags are used not as shortcut for a tag, which is not this case, since you are proposing a longer tag as synonym of a shorter tag; synonym tags are used when there are users who use two or more tags to mean the same thing. For example, if users would keep using [views-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-module) as tag for the Views module, and four new questions would use it every time the tag is edited from question, then [views-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-module) would be a candidate for being a synonym of [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views). Since users cannot use [drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7) as tag, there isn't the need to set it as synonym.

Comment: Technically, it should be possible to add "migration synonyms" not usable by people here directly. Hope it'll be done.

Comment: That could be useful, especially for those sites that are listed in the migration list. Since a question cannot be migrated from normal users if it doesn't contain at least one of the tags used in the receiving site, those migration synonym would be a way for the site to say "we accept these questions, if they use these tags in the original site." We are out of luck: Drupal Answers is not listed as migration site, and migrations from Stack Overflow are not much.