# How to deal with versions

Tags: discussion, tags

Due to the way Drupal 8+ operates, the vast majority of [8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8) applies just as well to Drupal 9 and Drupal 10 too but this might not be evident for newcomers. What do do here?

Comment: Some history on this for info: https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful & https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok

Comment: D8 came out four years after that discussion with a completely new vision on how backward compatibility happens we now D9 and D10 showing the vision works. There are _very_ few questions which truly are [8] -- and even those would need more elaborate tagging, for example path aliases became entities in 8.8 so questions would have different "best practice" answers 8.0-8.7 and 8.8+.

Comment: There was also this discussion led when Drupal 8 was long out: https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/15055. I also posted an answer there: **Use version tags only when they are really necessary to highlight a major difference between Drupal versions**.

Comment: Ah yeah, also this: https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3708/15055

Comment: @̷c̷h̷x̷ I agree with you, I just posted the links for info

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the times you'd simply **leave the tag out** and instead tell in the question body what version of Drupal you are currently working with. The farer away we get from Drupal 7, the more irrelevant the version tags will be.

And then you'd only use version tags for when something is really specific to a certain version. Like when something changed between Drupal 9 and Drupal 10, and you want to know how to make it work in Drupal 10, because the way how it worked in the past doesn't work anymore, you'd tag your question [10](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10).

This also complies with the usage guide of each version tag: You should not use it to tell what version of Drupal you are using, you should only use it when asking a question that is specific to just that version.

Comment: I agree of course, but this a) needs to be made into policy so people can start removing them from new question b) we have like 10k questions or something with a misleading tag.

Comment: @̷c̷h̷x̷ – There as some users that are aware of it and constantly remove them at best with a revision message that tells users why. And yes, there's a lot of posts that need to be adjusted.