# Can you appeal an edit rejection?

Tags: support

I sometimes edit questions for clarity and add information when necessary after further understanding the user when they explain in the comments, but I also tend to add the 8 or 7 tag to posts that omitted it. Partly for maintenance and partly because I figured it was helpful for people like me that display only questions that contain the 8 tag since that is the version I am most versed with. They are always accepted so I assumed that it was okay to make these changes. 
All of a sudden the latest ones of mine were rejected so now I'm banned from editing. I disagree that they should be rejected, but even if I refrain from making that particular kind of edit am I forever banned from editing? I feel like I'm a helpful member to the Drupal community and this seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Have you read https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/version-tags-in-2017-and-onward? No you won't be banned forever, I'm just on mobile but will look into it properly later and give you a real response if no one else has had a chance to by then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in question, the ban for edit suggestions is not forever.

For future edit suggestions I would consider the following points:

- Don't suggest an edit just to add a tag, especially when there are other things that need to be fixed (e.g. grammar, spelling, use of constructs that aren't standard English)
- Don't add tags that are not necessary

When you are suggesting an edit, two other users need to review it, so the edit should be worth the time they use to review it.

In Stack Exchange, tags have a specific meaning, apart from the specific meaning a tag has in a particolar site. For example, for us [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) is a tag for a question about the Views module, which should not added to questions where the OP says *I need to show a node as front page, but only when the user has a specific permission* (i.e. [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) doesn't mean *the question is about viewing a node, or a user profile*). For Stack Exchange in general, a tag means *this question is about this specific topic*; in particular, the version tags mean *this question is about this specific version, and not others*. This also means that [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) should not be used to mean *I am using Drupal 7*, in the same way a tag like [C#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) should not be used to mean *I am using C# 4.0*. In fact, the tag wiki for that tag says *The C# tag should be used if your question is not specific to C# 4.0*.
Using a version tag when it should not be used has two negative effects:

- Future readers would think the question applies only to a specific Drupal version, when it is not true
- We would have multiple questions for which the same answer applies (even with slightly differences)